# Google App Engine not showing full error message

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I have an interesting problem. One that I haven't encountered before. So, I have a Django application running in GAE, and for some user profiles it shows server error. It doesn't matter if the url contains username or user id or whatever, it still shows the error for the same users. The main problem is that GAE doesn't show the full error message. It shows this:

```
Exception in request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~creativeselector2-hrd/eredeti-py27-stable2-dj15nr-fb53-
    fbfix.380380587155289937/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    ...
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~creativ...(length 8832)
```

The ... in line 6 is my doing, I wanted to save you from reading through all the file list.
I even tried downloading logs via appcfg.py, I got the same results (ends with ...). So, my question is: is there a way to get the full error message? If not, how can I start debugging such an error? It only happens with a few user profiles, and nothing common between them. The only common thing I found, is that each usernames contain special characters (á, é), but another username also contains such letters and the url is working for them.

Thanks in advance,
Gabe

Comment: did you try to get your logs from your admin console?

Comment: Do you mean the Logs menu in appengine.google.com? I copied this error from there.

Comment: I actually meant the newest console (console.developers.google.com). But normally they should be the same. Give it a go anyway, it might be different in there :)

Comment: Then unfortunately, I think the answer will be no. As far as I know (I might get proven wrong), the logs shown on console.developers are the actual errors Google "records". I am curious to see if there are fuller logs somewhere